# How to compare "now" and a future time

Tags: java, android, calendar

I need to compare the time a local file was downloaded with a time in the future/past to see if the file needs to be re-downloaded to update it. I can get the time the local file was last downloaded with :

`long timeSinceCreateFile = myFile.lastModified();`

What I need is to check `timeSinceCreateFile` with a time that is the NEXT Friday at 21:30hs and if the current time: `System.currentTimeMillis()`
is in the future to this then re-download the file.

I've read heaps on Calendar, Time, Date, Joda-Time etc. but have not been able to figure out how to get a moment in time as a specific Day, Hour, Minuet, etc. that is RELATIVE to `timeSinceCreateFile`

**Edit**

I need to know the time in milliseconds between when a file was downloaded (or last modified) `long timeSinceCreateFile = myFile.lastModified();` and the FOLLOWING Friday at 21:30hs (as in the Friday at 21:30hrs AFTER `timeSinceCreateFile`)

I can then compare the "FOLLOWING FRIDAY AT 21:30hrs" milliseconds to the current time 'System.currentTimeMillis()` and if one is greater than the other re-download the file.

Hope this clarified my question, if not let me know because I really need help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Use math? E.g., add time to `timeSinceCreateFile`?

Comment: I think I didn't get the point. `System.currentTimeMillis()` can NEVER be in the future of the NEXT friday! So please clarify your question.

Comment: Both of these dates are represented by a long integer so you just need to determine which one is greater than the other, unless I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll re-jig the question

Comment: Also, why are you counting mil. sec? why not just to compare dates and  modify?

Comment: I don't need in milliseconds, I really just need boolean, if one is greater or less than the other. I just thought milliseconds is the best way to compare exact times. If there is a boolean way to do this that would be great!

Comment: @DaveNewton That's exactly what I want to do. What I need though is a "long" of the NEXT Friday that can be compared to `timeSinceCreateFile`

Comment: Sorry all, been away for a few days...   I was thinking this question was a bit of a noob question but it's obviously not a trivial this to do. I'll try both Meno Hochschild and Basil Bourque answers and post results. The Joda Time thing is looking simpler but we'll see...

Comment: @Ash Just to note: As far as I can see in proposed Joda-solution, it does not take into account the walltime 21:30 comparing with current time so it is not an equivalent solution.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Yeah, I noticed that too which is why I an perusing your suggestion. Lots to read.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your temporal condition "next Friday at 21:30" is hard to realize** in standard Java-library using `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`.

In **Joda-Time** it also requires a non-trivial workaround (again with loop).

In **Java-8 (new time library JSR-310 in package java.time)** an acceptable solution using specialized methods in [TemporalAdjusters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-) is possible, but since you operate on Android, this is not the way to go.

---

Instead here an alternative solution in my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/releases) which does not need any error-prone loops or complex conditions:

```
import static net.time4j.PlainDate.DAY_OF_WEEK;
import static net.time4j.Weekday.FRIDAY;

File myFile = new File("");
long timeSinceCreateFile = myFile.lastModified();

// conversion to global timestamp in Time4J-format
Moment fileTSP = TemporalTypes.MILLIS_SINCE_UNIX.transform(timeSinceCreateFile);

// what ever you need (or just TZID timezone = Timezone.ofSystem().getID();)
TZID timezone = AMERICA.MONTREAL;

// "next friday" is a local time condition => convert to local timestamp
PlainTimestamp localTSP = fileTSP.toZonalTimestamp(timezone);
PlainTime walltime2130 = PlainTime.of(21, 30);

// move to next time 21:30 (possibly on next day) and then to next or same Friday
localTSP =
    localTSP.with(PlainTime.COMPONENT.setToNext(walltime2130))
            .with(DAY_OF_WEEK.setToNextOrSame(FRIDAY));

// convert current time to local timestamp and compare at 21:30
boolean downloadNeeded = SystemClock.inZonalView(timezone).now().isAfter(localTSP);
```

Comment: Just curios, why is the new java.time package not the way to go in Android??

Comment: @Ash Android closely but not exactly follows Java-6-API so the new JSR-310-API is simply not available on Android platforms. Please have a look on this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62192), too (which was declined by Google). As workaround - you might experiment with [Threeten-BP](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) however. But I think Time4J is already now better on many areas and has definitely more innovation power. The code example above will even be further simplified in next version 1.2 (without if-clause).

Comment: Query: Which .jar file is best? time4j-core or time4j-olson??

Comment: @Ash The core is always needed. olson is optional and necessary if you want to refer to standard timezone identifiers by enum or want to parse localized timezone names.

Comment: Thanks Meno Hochschild heaps for finding my question! It took me a while to decipher your code (due to work, sleep, reading, etc...) but it works perfectly! Could you please tell me the idea/concept behind using the word "wall" to describe specific relative positions in time (I think), I understand the code, but I would like to know the meaning of this.    THANKS AGAIN!!

Comment: @Ash The term "walltime" is just meant in a descriptive way standing for a simple analogue clock on the wall. Like the type "PlainTime", it has NO reference to any timezone in internal state. Well, I should really find time to write a good tutorial about the library. Although there are many classes, it is not necessary to learn all of them. Often, just apply the same schematic approach starting with the four basic types (PlainXYZ or Moment), and the IDE will tell you by code completion what you can do. A tutorial should show this simplicity in usage.

Comment: @Ash I have now added new code which is possible with next version. The new extension (with new element "PlainTime.COMPONENT") is already on github but not yet released.

Answer (score 1):

GregorianCalendar ? set the date to your year, month, day, 21:30, set day of week to friday. Use getTime to get a long millisecs. This will give you a UNIX time for some friday 21:30 close to your date. Keep adding or removing the number of milliseconds in a week until the time minus your file time is in the range [0 number of milliseconds in a week]. Warning with month, it's 0 based.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long fileCreateTime = new Date().getTime();

    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(new Date(fileCreateTime));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    long MILLISECS_IN_A_WEEK = 7*24*60*60*1000;

    long calendarMillisecs = calendar.getTime().getTime();
    while(calendarMillisecs<fileCreateTime){
        calendarMillisecs += MILLISECS_IN_A_WEEK;
    }
    while(calendarMillisecs>fileCreateTime+MILLISECS_IN_A_WEEK){
        calendarMillisecs -= MILLISECS_IN_A_WEEK;
    }

    System.out.println(new Date(calendarMillisecs));


}
```

Ugly, but will work.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid java.util.Date & .Calendar

Avoid java.util.Date and .Calendar because they are notoriously troublesome, flawed, and confusing. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

In Joda-Time 2.4.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime start = DateTime.now(  timeZone );
// DateTime start = new DateTime( fileLastModifiedMillis, timeZone );
DateTime dateTime = start; 
while ( dateTime.getDayOfWeek() != DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY ) {
    dateTime = dateTime.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

To compare…

```
boolean isLate = oneDateTime.isAfter( someOtherDateTime );
```